# cordova plugin not installing properly

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am facing some issue while installing plugins from cordova, as I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

**Command:**

```
cordova -v
```

**Result:**

```
4.3.0
```

**Command:**

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

**Result:**

```
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.camera" via plugin registry 
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at getJson (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\metadata.js:29:31)
    at Object.exports.save_fetch_metadata (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\metadata .js:56:24)
    at C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\fetch.js:148:18
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

**Command:**

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

**Result:**

```
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git" via git clone 
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at getJson (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\metadata.js:29:31)
    at Object.exports.save_fetch_metadata (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\metadata .js:56:24)
    at C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\fetch.js:148:18
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

It seems something get changed within my project files because same plugin are adding correctly without any error in new project. But I really don't get what has changed.

Comment: Is your NPM and Node updated? Try `npm install npm -g`, then `npm install node -g`.

Comment: It seems to be a network related issue. Possibly the file was unable to download fully. Check your network connectivity status.

Comment: @Nisar connectivity is good

Comment: @Keval no luck for me :(

Comment: Some of the header files could be missing. So, try to re-install the cordova, Because, I tried to install the same version in my PC and worked correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I had a corrupted fetch.json too. I ran it through jsonlint.com and found the missing comma right away.

Answer (score 1):

it's been a while now, but I've just fixed this on my project by reverting the changes on the fetch.json file which got corrupted after a merging.